# Two pieces of code with the same logic. One gives expected output while the other does not

Tags: c++

```
char xtime(char m)
{
    //calculates the m value by checking m,if m is less than 0x80 hexadecimal
    // then it is left shifted else it is left shifted and xor'ed with 0x1b.
    if(m<0x80)
    {
        m<<=1;
    } else {
        m=(((m)<<1)^0x1b);
    }

    printf("%#01x ",m&0xff);
    return m;
}
```

This code doesnt show the expected output if m=0x80(which is 0x1b),it gives the output as 0 in hexadecimal.

```
#define xtime(a) (((a)<0x80)?(a)<<1:(((a)<<1)^0x1b) )
```

This code works and gives the expected result .

Could you please help as to what is wrong with the functional code and how is it solved in the second code.

Comment: `char` may be signed depending on the environment, and if `char` is 8-bit long and is signed, `0x80` may not fit in it. The second code should work if value having `int` type is passed because `int` can hold integers upto at least 32767.

Comment: it's a good idea to only use `char` for characters. If you need a small integer type, use either `signed char` or `unsigned char`. In your case, the latter seems to be what you need.

Comment: For C++, you should consider `inline` instead of macros.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: a better idea is to use `uint8_t` or `int8_t` type.

Comment: @Thomas : sure is :)

Comment: changing char to unsigned char did the trick...and yes il make the definition inline instead of macro.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that in your environment

- `char` is signed
- `char` is 8-bit long
- two's compliment is used to express negative integers
- if a signed integer to convert to cannot store original value, upper bits are simply thrown away

`0x80` is too big to store into `char` variable, and it will be interpreted as `-128`. `-128` is smaller than `0x80`, so `m <<= 1;` is executed.
The result of this shift is `-256`, and its binary reprensentation is `0xffffff00`, and `m` will get the last 8 bits, which is `0`. That is what you get.

The macro will work if `0x80` is passed to `a`, because the calculation will be done using `int`, and `int` can hold integers upto at least `32767`.

Comment: Plus signed integer-type overflow is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @YSC I thought `m` as operand will be converted to `int` via integer promotions because another operand `1` is `int`, and conversion to small signed integer is implementation-defined (N1256 6.3.1.3). Am I wrong?

Comment: It's worse: in fact `if (m < 0x80)` is always true since `m` is a `signed char`.